# Android Emulator was not loading in android 4.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-4.0

I know there was Lot of them asked this question here but I checked and followed all the question but still, I have the Same Problem

My System Configuration

[image]

I am using `Android Studio 4.0 Version` and my `SDK` was

[image]

my Processor was AMD processor So i was unable to install `HAMX`

[image]

My Virtual Device was `pixel 3a` and I linked my setting below of that virtual device

[image]

**Error Msg List**

Error

[image]

i was Trying to run a Simple Program but the emulator was not running when it start running it shows the below error msg First

**for this Error lot of people suggest using **" `advancedFeatures.ini`"** and that doesn't Solve my Problem**.

so I just hit ok and try to run the Program in Emulator, **my emulator takes too long to process and it displays the below error logs and also said " Timed Out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online "**

[image]

for this error and check all the Stackflow questions and nothing will Solve my problem pls suggest how to run project in emulator

```html
02:45 PM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\karthickyuvan\AndroidStudioProjects\Log

02:45 PM    Gradle build finished in 23 s 176 ms

02:46 PM    Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 35828 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

02:46 PM    Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 35828 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

02:46 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

02:46 PM    Emulator: Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.

02:51 PM    Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 53704 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

02:51 PM    Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 53708 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

02:51 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

02:52 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using AMD Processor so first enable Virtualization in Bios
2. Go to Control panel Add/Remove and Select " Turn Features On/Off" then enable hypervisor and VMP then Do restart
3. Go to AVD manager and Choose Choose Pixel 2 then select Api Level 28 and install and now Run

Also check adb in command prompt it not recognize then set path variable for sdk platform tools in environment variable.